# Windows won't give choice to dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, multi-boot

I have a laptop that has a dual boot Windows 7 and 8.1. Before, whenever I start my machine there will be choices which OS I want to boot then there is a check box beside it. Last night I accidentally ticked the box and booted to windows 7. Now I cannot boot to windows 8.1 anymore, startup wont give me choices. When I checked the system management it says that I only have one OS and it is default to windows 7. Anyone can help ? thanks in advance!

Comment: Checkbox? That doesn't seem to be what normal Windows boot menu will provide. How exactly did you set up your dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dual-boot Repair tool for Windows 10/8/7](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) to fix dual boot.

It has "Automatic Repair" option which will list all recognized Windows systems and fix booting to latest OS - in your case Windows 8.1.

To add Windows 7 to boot menu (if missing after fix) use [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net), on F9-key it will automatically add any missing Windows OS from boot menu.